# Free SVN repo server without requiring a project

Tags: c++, svn, hosting, free

I want to know if there are any free Subversion repository hosting servers where you don't need to have a 'project' to host your C++ files in.

I don't have a actual project, but I want to store my C++ in an SVN repository. I am looking for something like [OpenSVN](https://opensvn.csie.org/) where you can upload your C++ files, but it requires you to have a project.

Can you recommend a Subversion hosting service where you can upload your files to an account, rather than a project. Something like: `http://www.test-svn.com/~nathanpc/`

Comment: What's the problem with creating a project, even if it's just "myPracticeProject@, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/)?  It's free and you don't need to have a project.